# Undefined variable: error while running the raw sql query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am trying to insert data using raw SQL statement using laravel's `DB::statement()` but the problem is when I run it in a seeder the console think the password is variable instead of a string

here is the code

```
DB::statement("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`, `password`, `permissions`, `activated`, `activation_code`, `activated_at`, `last_login`, `persist_code`, `reset_password_code`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
    VALUES
        (13, '1@1.com', '$2y$10$FGKgaSVG6ZQS19mg9c2nMutVjQuIL0OMYsXcB4ZkE5dntL72Wq8N6', NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Edwin', 'Lugo', '2016-01-12 23:49:01', '2016-01-12 23:49:01'),
        (14, '2@1.com', '$2y$10$xIruVm4ju60hIOahIjaP4ewZbVYO69Xwr4IOFw7D5H/74wXNQ8RlO', NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Max', 'Bonilla ', '2016-01-12 23:50:21', '2016-01-12 23:50:21'),
        (15, '3@1.COM', '$2y$10$tmhzXsF5jlTwWDXRObzHLOAmZzDcMDK0GdbImUnUYtfIn.WWaIj8a', NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Denny', 'Tran ', '2016-01-12 23:51:42', '2016-01-12 23:51:42')");
```

It results in

[image: Console error]

**PS:** I am using Laravel 4

Comment: Using single quotes from string encapsulation in PHP. `$FGKgaSVG6ZQS19mg9c2nMutVjQuIL0OMYsXcB4ZkE5dntL72Wq8N6` is being read as a variable because of the double quotes. Use double quotes for SQL string encapsulation.

Comment: @chris85 the whole query is in double quotes would it still read it as variable?

Comment: Yes, change the whole thing to single quotes and move the inner parts to double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PHP` processes variables in double quotes. Your password string is being read as a variable because of the `$` and trailing text (`$2` isn't causing issues because that is an invalid variable name in PHP so it doesn't even try to process it).

Simple demo of issue: https://3v4l.org/mM211
Simple demo of correction: https://3v4l.org/YWKtC

How your code should look:

```
'INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`, `password`, `permissions`, `activated`, `activation_code`, `activated_at`, `last_login`, `persist_code`, `reset_password_code`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
    VALUES
        (13, "1@1.com", "$2y$10$FGKgaSVG6ZQS19mg9c2nMutVjQuIL0OMYsXcB4ZkE5dntL72Wq8N6", NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "Edwin", "Lugo", "2016-01-12 23:49:01", "2016-01-12 23:49:01"),
        (14, "2@1.com", "$2y$10$xIruVm4ju60hIOahIjaP4ewZbVYO69Xwr4IOFw7D5H/74wXNQ8RlO", NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "Max", "Bonilla ", "2016-01-12 23:50:21", "2016-01-12 23:50:21"),
        (15, "3@1.COM", "$2y$10$tmhzXsF5jlTwWDXRObzHLOAmZzDcMDK0GdbImUnUYtfIn.WWaIj8a", NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "Denny", "Tran ", "2016-01-12 23:51:42", "2016-01-12 23:51:42")'
```